# How to turn an int pointer to an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So this was presented in our class (I was absent that time):

```
typedef struct{

  int *items;
  int size;
  int max;
}list;
```

and a list was passed to a function:

```
void append(list *l, int x){

  if(l->size==l->max){
      expand(l);
  }
  l->items[l->size++] = x;
}
```

My question is, how can an int pointer have an index? I thought indexes were used on arrays? Can that be done?

I'm new to C. So yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer is simply the address to the memory space allocated for your object/array/int.
You can have a pointer to anything memory-related in C. You just say, here is my int, here is my array, etc...

Comment: Nitpicking on this "*A pointer is simply the address ...*" - strictly speaking it should read: "*The value stored in a pointer is simply the address ...*".

Answer (score 4):

A pointer can point at either 1 or n elements of its type. There is no way of telling which it is just from the declaration. We can assume that `items` is the address of the first element of an array. Since arrays store their elements in sequence, when you index the pointer, you really apply an offset from the first address. Hence, you index into the array that the pointer points at.

```
int values[5];    // Simple array.
int* p = values;  // p points to the first element of the array values.
p[2] = 34;        // Equivalent to values[2] = 34;
```

Answer (score 0):

Any pointer can be treated as an array. An array is a sort of 2nd class citizen, and in most places the compiler treats an array as a pointer, and whenever an array is passed to a function, the compiler actually passes the address of the first element of the array. In fact,  `a[b]` is considered to be `*(a + b)` (which can lead to some pretty incomprehensible code!)

So in your structure, `items` can be treated as a plain integer pointer, or the address of an array (as is done here).

Comment: actually, "and whenever an array is passed to a function, the compiler actually passes the first element of the array." is not true.  what is actually passed is the 'address' of the first element of the array, not the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

> How to turn an int pointer to an array

Strictly speaking: You cannot.

Comment: Hello, I talked to a classmate the other day, and they said they used malloc. like this  l->items = malloc(sizeof(int)*5); 

And after that they have used it as an array.

Comment: @CedezMarieG.Gulane: "*turning into*" is different from "*using as*". Using a pointer like an array, will not turn it into one. For example try applying the `sizeof` operator to a variable declare as array and to a pointer having been allocated the same size of memory. You will get different results.